# Unable to allocate new TLS context

Tags: active-directory, postfix-mta, starttls

I have postfix 3.3.0 and Active Directory on Server 2019. I want the connection to be secure and to validate the server certificate.

When trying to send an email, I am unable to and see this in `syslog`.

```
postfix/submission/smtpd[7432]: warning: dict_ldap_set_tls_options: Unable to allocate new TLS context -1: Can't contact LDAP server
```

Here's the contents of `/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf`

```
bind = yes
bind_dn = {valid bind account}
bind_pw = {valid bind password}
version = 3
timeout = 20

size_limit = 1
expansion_limit = 0

start_tls = yes
tls_require_cert = yes
tls_ca_cert_file = /var/spool/postfix/mydomain.tld.crt

server_host = ldap://dc.mydomain.tld/
search_base = dc=mydomain,dc=tld
scope = sub
query_filter = (&(objectClass=person)(mail=%s))

result_attribute = mail
result_format = %s
```

With this configuration, `postmap -q test@mydomain.tld ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf` works. `openssl s_client -starttls ldap -connect dc.mydomain.tld:389` also works (no validation errors). Even with `tls_require_cert = no`, it still fails. When `start_tls = no`, everything works fine.

Before I specified `tls_ca_cert_file`, I imported my .crt into `ca-certificates`. The error I received was `postfix/postmap[4994]: error: dict_ldap_connect: Unable to set STARTTLS: -11: Connect error`. It seems Postfix doesn't read from the computer cert store. After testing with `tls_ca_cert_file` from my `home`, it changed to the error I'm getting now, -1. I first tried from `/etc/postfix`, then now chroot home (based on an Internet suggestion Postfix couldn't access it).

Answer (score 0):

I realized I made the classic mistake of installing from the stock repositories, and ended up with an old version. I ended up compiling Postfix from source.

```
sudo groupadd postfix
sudo groupadd postdrop
sudo useradd -c "Postfix Daemon User" -d /var/spool/postfix -g postfix -s /bin/false -u 32 postfix
wget http://cdn.postfix.johnriley.me/mirrors/postfix-release/official/postfix-3.6.2.tar.gz
tar xzf postfix-3.6.2.tar.gz
sudo apt-get install libdb-dev gcc m4 make libsasl2-dev openssl libssl-dev libldb-dev libldap2-dev
cd postfix-3.6.2/
make makefiles CCARGS="-I/usr/include/openssl -I/usr/include/sasl/ -DUSE_TLS -DHAS_LDAP -DUSE_SASL_AUTH -DUSE_CYRUS_SASL" AUXLIBS="-lssl -lcrypto -lldap -llber -lsasl2"
make
sudo make install
```